# CSS Image Gallery modification

Tags: jquery, css, image, xhtml, gallery

I'm creating an event website which would, obviously, include an event calendar. I'm using this example http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-image-gallery/ for the gallery, hover effects, etc.

However, I'd like to modify the above example so that when you click the thumbnail, the enlarged image stays until you click another thumbnail etc.

How would I go about doing this given the code in the example? Is it possible without jQuery/Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JavaScript to do this.

The example uses `:hover` to achieve this effect. Unfortunately to need the page to "remember"  something. CSS can't do that by itself.

You'd need to copy the styles contained in the `:hover` declaration to a class, then assign that class to the element on mouse-over. This also means you have to remove that class from this item when another item is hovered.

Comment: Hmm.. makes sense! Thanks for the reply! I'll have to go update myself on Javascript first, though. Lol. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.thumbnail:hover span` style in the CSS to something like `.thumbnail_clicked span` and add this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').click(function() {
        var cname = 'thumbnail_clicked';
        $(this).addClass(cname).siblings().removeClass(cname);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/DxArs/